# tinymce only bold and italic buttons with rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, tinymce, tinymce-rails

I want use only **bold** and **italic** with TinyMce. I don't want more features, only bold and italic buttons.

1º I have installed the gem [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails)

2º I have a file `config/tinymce.yml` with the next content:

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
theme_advanced_buttons1 : 
  - bold
  - italic
theme_advanced_buttons2 : 
theme_advanced_buttons3 :
```

3º On the view:

```
<%= text_area_tag :editor, "", :class => "tinymce", :rows => 20, :cols => 120 %>
<%= tinymce %>
```

However I can see all buttons, and all toolbars.

**How can I only use bold and italic buttons. I want remove all other features and toolbars. Thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

e2. For your specific situation, I think the problem is you are using the 4.0+version of the gem which has the 4+ version of tinymce in it. They changed the name of the advanced theme to modern. Among a bunch of other changes that I didn't bother figuring out.

Just downgrade your gem version to 3.5.8(which is what I am using) and the code you already had will work fine.

e3. Config file for version 4+ is simple:

```
toolbar1: bold  italic
menubar: false
statusbar: false
```

menubar and statusbar remove those respective bars.

The master branch Readme is outdated, [check out the readme for the version 4+ gem.](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails/tree/tinymce-4)

Comment: With this code I can see in console the next message: `Failed to load: http://localhost:3000/assets/tinymce/themes/advanced/theme.js` and the editor doesn't works! Thanks!

Comment: Does just modifying the yaml to add the default work?

Comment: Ah, you are probably using the latest version of the gem which has tinymce 4 which changes a bunch of stuff around. Among other things it changes the name of the advanced theme to modern. Consider specifying `gem 'tinymce-rails', '3.5.8'` in your gemfile and updating. Not sure what 4.0 adds to the thing, since none of the documentation seems properly updated. For your use case(and mine) pre 4.0 versions are fine.

Comment: Thanks, now is working fine. But editor is a horror. It's very ugly, be possible to get this with the new version? I need it for the new version. Thanks!

Comment: If you want 4, checkout their [documentation for 4](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails/tree/tinymce-4). Personally I'm not sure it's prettier and it might have some bugs when it comes to overflowing its containers. I'll update the answer with a config for 4.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, only answer, but if you think it's ugly, try CKEditor.  Much more attractive, and it has the same toolbar customization.

Comment: Thank you, but now I'm checking this editor. I will take a look to CkEditor!

Comment: I did the same, which is the only reason I posted.  :)  I started out with TinyMCE, got it all customized, and then went, "GAH, this is ugly and unwieldy."